# Issue in custom action in install shield 2010

Tags: installshield-2010

I want to make a script that open port in installation and close it in un-installation
I made the both scripts but every time
script for open port runs in install and in uninstall so after uninstalling i have 2 rules for open that port and close port never run

I have attached screen shots about my configuration in this custom actions

http://community.flexerasoftware.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=9100&stc=1&d=1307473659

http://community.flexerasoftware.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=9101&stc=1&d=1307473673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below conditions
NOT Installed to run only during install.
REMOVE="ALL" to run only during uninstall.